# How to do an ad-hoc distribution an app inside organization (in-house app distribution)?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-house-distribution

I am trying to find a step by step procedure for deploying couple of apps inside an organization. I am not able to find a step-by-step answer for it.

Comment: Why do you have three separate questions for the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's [Distributing Apps for iOS Devices](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/). It explains how to deploy apps that you buy through the App Store's volume purchase program as well as how to prepare and distribute apps that you've written within your organization.